# Is the High Elf's extra cantrip in addition to cantrips from your class?

Tags: dnd-5e, racial-traits, cantrips, spellcasting, elf

I read that High Elves could chose a cantrip from the wizard spells, but is it additional to your own class cantrips, or is it counted as one of them?

For this instance, I want to make a Cleric which has at the beginning 3 cantrips. If I chose to be High Elf, would that mean I'll have 4 cantrips, or does it count as one of the 3?

Comment: Read to me like "extra catnip for High Elf?"...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You would have four cantrips.

The general rule is that features from your race, class, archetype, or whatever, are additional to one another. Features do not stack only when explicitly noted by the rules.

Comment: It is in addition, as Justin said. Think about this- if it wasn't, and you picked a class that doesn't have spellcasting, the racial bonus would effectively read "one of your zero cantrips can be from the wizard class", which obviously doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 13):

It's an additional cantrip. In the case you're proposing, your High Elf Cleric would know 3 Cleric cantrips and 1 Wizard cantrip.