# Does Eldritch Knight grant 2 Cantrips known in addition to a High Elf's knowing 1 to begin with?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, fighter

Starting as a High Elf lets me know a single wizard cantrip at level 1. By the time I hit level 3 and get my archetype, Eldritch Knight, I am supposed to know 2.

I'm just a bit confused on whether this would mean 2 overall, or 2 in addition to the High Elf starting cantrip, meaning 3 known cantrips at level 3.

Comment: Hi Reece, welcome to Stack RPG. I've suggested this question be closed as a duplicate, because it's already been asked and answered, here:

https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59441/extra-cantrip-for-high-elf

Comment: Hi again Reece. As you see, this question got 'closed' as a duplicate of a previously asked one. If the older question answers your concern, great. If not, then you would edit your question to show how your question is different. 

Once again, welcome, and I hope you are enjoying the site.

Please take "the tour" of the site when you have a minute: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour

Answer (score 6):

## 2 in addition, for a total of 3.

The High-Elf cantrip does not count for the amount of cantrips you know. You will have an extra one, for a total of 3.

From this [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/59441/extra-cantrip-for-high-elf),

> The general rule is that features from your race, class, archetype, or whatever, are additional to one another. Features do not stack only when explicitly noted by the rules.